# Command MergeSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm getting an error when I try to build my MacOS app in Xcode.

```
Command MergeSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code.

error: umbrella for module 'PDFKit' already covers this directory
        umbrella header "PDFKit.h"
                        ^
error: inferred submodules require a module with an umbrella
        module * { export * }
```

Most of my Swift files have:

```
import Cocoa
import Quartz
```

I'm using PDFKit a lot, so I'm guessing it's something to do with importing and referencing the headers. The error occurs on Xcode 11.1 and 11.2.

I have tried a Clean Build, without success. There are other threads about this, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690619/build-fails-with-command-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code), which seem to suggest that it's a non-specific, intermittent problem.

Comment: Do you #import <PDFKit/PDFKit.h> in code? You got this error because the Quartz framework umbrella header already has PDFKIt import.

Comment: I'm using Swift, so I just used the import Quartz statements as above. Note that after removing the import commands and then restoring them exactly as before, the problem fixed itself.

Comment: I am able to fix this by replacing PDFKit import by Quartz and deleted PDFKit.framework from the build phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the nature of the error messages, I deleted all the `import Quartz` statements from all the files, then tried to Build. Obviously, it then failed because of unknown objects.

Then, I restored the `import Quartz` lines, and the problem was fixed.

This does seem to be a bug in Xcode.

Comment: If you are using interoperability in your swift project, ensure you replace any `#import <PDFKit/PDFKit.h>` with the appropriate replacement `#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>`.

Comment: I think we're all already Quartz over PDFKit that, aren't we? But I'm not sure I know what 'using interoperability' is.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the compilation error was due to the import of a custom framework that in turns imported PDFKit. I changed the `import PDFKit` in the framework code with `import Quartz`, and that workaround solved the problem in Xcode 11.6.

Xcode 12 beta 3 seems to work better and does not require any workaround to build the existing code.